# How do you make a copy constructor/assignment operator for a class that contains a shared_ptr? C++

Tags: c++, class, constructor, deep-copy

Say, I have a class .h file named Ninja

I have two member functions and the default name is set to Ninja master and discple_ child is set to  nullptr

Below is a snippit of the public/private of my class:

```
private:

    std::string name_;
    std::shared_ptr<Ninja> disciples_;


  public:
    Ninja(std::string name = "Ninja Master")
      : name_{name},
        disciples_{std::shared_ptr<Ninja>(nullptr)}
     {}
    ~Ninja() = default;     
Ninja(const Ninja& copy2);  //trying to make a copy constructor here
Ninja& operator=(const Ninja&);   // I also need help creating an assignment operator too
```

I want to make a deep copy constructor but I am getting errors.

Below is the snippet for my deep copy constructor in the .cpp file.

```
Ninja::Ninja(const Ninja& copy2) {
   Ninja a();
   a = copy2; //error cannot convert const Ninja to Ninja() in assignment
}
```

Comment: This `Ninja a();` is a function declaration. A question asked a few minutes ago was having exactly the same problem!

Comment: You can just write `Ninja a;` but I'm not sure why you're doing that

Comment: ok I changed it to: 
name_ = copy2.name_;
  disciples_= copy2.disciples_;  This gives no error, but I don't know if it's copying correctly

Comment: And, in the copy constructor, resist temptation to write `Ninja a = copy2` as - although it looks like an assignment - it actually calls the copy constructor.   The result would therefore be infinite recursion.     You might also want to question why a copy constructor should also create an object of the same type  i.e.   why should the copy constructor, which is called to initialise an instance of `Ninja`, create a second instance of `Ninja`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::shared\_ptr deep copy object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19969260/stdshared-ptr-deep-copy-object)

Comment: Aside: `std::shared_ptr<Ninja> disciples_` is confusing. `std::shared_ptr<Ninja>` is zero or one `Ninja`s, "disciples" implies many. Perhaps you want `std::vector<Ninja> disciples_`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of a deep copy constructor:

```
Ninja(const Ninja& other) 
    : name_(other.name_), 
      disciples_(other.disciples_ ? 
          std::make_shared<Ninja>(*other.disciples_) : 
          std::shared_ptr<Ninja>{}
      )
{}
```

It will create a **new** `shared_ptr` that will hold a copy of `Ninja` object managed by `other.disciples_`.

If you don't need a **deep** copy, just omit the copy constuctor. It will be implicitly defined and will make a copy of `shared_ptr` automatically.

> I don't understand the usage of the ? ternary operator. Please explain.

We first [check](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_bool) that `shared_ptr` stores a non-null pointer. If it does, we [dereference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator*) it and create a new one using the copy constructor of `Ninja`, if it doesn't, we create an empty `shared_ptr`. If `disciples_` is never empty by design, this check can be omitted.

Comment: Thank you, this works. I don't understand the usage of the ? ternary operator. Please explain

Comment: @user10005002 It basically ensures that your `shared_ptr` is not empty when you deference it (`*other.disciples_`). `std::unique_ptr` has a [conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_bool) that converts it to a bool (true if and only if the pointer is not null)

Comment: @user10005002, added a few words.

Answer (score 1):

`Ninja a();` declares a function.

If you want to create a `Ninja` object, drop the parentheses : `Ninja a;`

---

The copy constructor could be implemented like this:

```
Ninja::Ninja(const Ninja &n)
:   name_(n.name_),
    disciples_(n.disciples_)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below -

```
  if( copy2.disciples_ )
    {   
        this->disciples_ = make_shared<Ninja>();
        this->disciples_->name_ = copy2.disciples_->name_;
        this->disciples_->disciples_= copy2.disciples_->disciples_;
    }   
    else
    {   
        this->disciples_ = copy2.disciples_;
    }
```

Comment: disciples_ has an unknown x amount of children. Is there a way to loop through it using pointers?